# test if netcdf file is valid without crashing

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I am reading multiple netcdf files using the `ncread` function in matlab.
For a reason unknown to me, some files (described by `FILEPATH` in the following) are not properly read and `ncread` crashes, producing the error message:

`Error using internal.matlab.imagesci.nc/openToRead (line 1259)
Could not open FILEPATH for reading.`

`Error in internal.matlab.imagesci.nc (line 121) this.openToRead();`

`Error in ncread (line 53)
ncObj   = internal.matlab.imagesci.nc(ncFile);`

`Error in MY_FUNCTION (line 102)
Lon = nanmean(ncread(FILEPATH,'Lon'));`

If you know of a method to test netcdf files without crashing, or if you understand what produces this error, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check `FILEPATH` contant is correct? Could you post the the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Filepath is valid and links to a valid netcdf file. I suspect it might happen when the netcdf file was not correctly closed in a prior attempt to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to wrap the possibly-failing statement in a `try`/`catch` statement to intercept the thrown exception before interrupting the function execution, like this:

```
function [out1, out2, ...] = MY_FUNCTION(arg1, arg2, ...)

        %//Initial code

        try
                Lon_data = ncread(FILEPATH,'Lon');
        catch ME
                warning('MY_FUNCTION:ncread', 'Could not load because <<%s>>',ME.message);
                %//Do something to recover from error
                %//Return from function if recover not possible
        end;
        Lon = nanmean(Lon_data);

        %//Rest of the code

end
```

Please note that `...` in the function signature above is not valid MATLAB syntax, but rather something that says *"here are some inputs and outputs that I don't know how they are declared"*; please substitute with your proper in/out declaration.